# SQL Server : how to join this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Advert table, Newspaper column takes integer value.

```
  Newspaper
      1
      2
      3
```

`Newspaper` table like this

```
NewspaperName UnitPrice
 A              12.00
 B              11.00
 C              5.00
```

Query;

```
select 
    case 
       when a.Newspaper = 1 then 'A' 
       when a.Newspaper = 2 then 'B' 
       when a.Newspaper = 3 then 'C'
       when a.Newspaper = 4 then 'D' 
       else 'Empty' 
    end as NewspaperName 
from Advert 
left join...
```

It's the little foolish. But I want to left join `Advert` table to `Newspaper`. How to join this?

Comment: Why does the `Advert` table not use the primary key type of the `Newspaper` table? Looks like a broken design.

Comment: It's designed like this. Bad design. @Oded

Comment: That's my point. No chance you can fix the design? Add an integer column to `Newspaper` that matches what you have in `Advert` and join on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use your "translation query" as a subquery:

```
SELECT AdvertTranslated.whatever1, Newspaper.whatever2 FROM
    (select case when a.Newspaper = 1 then 'A'
                 when a.Newspaper = 2 then 'B'
                 when a.Newspaper = 3 then 'C' 
                 when a.Newspaper = 4 then 'D'
                 else 'Empty' 
            end as NewspaperName,
            whatever1
       from Advert) AdvertTranslated
    LEFT JOIN Newspaper ON AdvertTranslated.NewspaperName = Newspaper.NewspaperName
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of strange to join 2 tables without a foreign key. Either way, if your maps are A -> 1, B -> 2 and so on you can get the [ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx) value of each letter and subtract by 64 to get a direct mapping.

Then you'll get:

```
SELECT * -- whatever you want to select
FROM Advert
LEFT JOIN Newspaper ON Advert.Newspaper = ASCII(Newspaper.NewspaperName) - 64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Advert table(newspaper int)
insert @Advert values(1), (2), (3), (4)

declare @Newspaper table(NewspaperName char(1), unitprice money)
insert @Newspaper values('A', 12.00), ('B', 11.00), ('C', 5.00)

SELECT a.newspaper, coalesce(b.Newspapername, 'Empty') NewspaperName, b.unitprice 
FROM @Advert a
LEFT JOIN
@Newspaper b
ON char(a.newspaper + 64) = b.NewspaperName
```